# Two Rooks v/s Queen End game

Tags: endgame, queens, rooks

Is Two Rooks, King v/s Queen, King in the end game is a theoritical draw in chess?

No player can win by any tactics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most positions with K+R+R vs K+Q are either dead draws or quickly come down to checkmate, a win with K+R vs K, or a loss with K+R vs K+Q.  But occasionally one may run into a longer analysis.  According to https://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/longest-checkmates/longest-checkmates.shtml the longest K+R+R vs K+Q win is a mate in 29, and the longest loss is mate in 46; to be sure these counts include the K+R/K and K+Q/K+R codas, but it still takes about 15 moves to get there.

Comment: To add the draw scenario which seems to be most probable to me: The RR side threatens a steamroller on the enemy king, with no rook threatened by a fork, and the Q side saves itself with perpetual check.